# How do you program game states in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

You can use frames in Flash ActionScript to hold a welcome screen, game content, and a game over screen; you can create an enum of game states in Microsoft XNA and draw all graphics and text when you call that state in the Draw method. How would you do this in HTML5 and JavaScript? I have a feeling that this can be done by showing and hiding div's, but I'm not entirely sure how to do it.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_SelectGame" runat="server" CssClass="BigText">
    <asp:ListItem>MatchMe (Memory)</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Royal Jewels (Bejeweled)</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Tetris</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<div id="Welcome" class="Welcome">
    <asp:Button ID="BTN_StartGame" runat="server" CssClass="Button" />
</div>
<div id="Game" class="Game">
</div>
<div id="GameOver" class="GameOver">
    <asp:Button ID="BTN-Replay" CssClass="Button" runat="server" />
</div>
```

The code above is an example of how I would set up a game page on my site (http://www.graphics-geek.com).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a state machine I'm planning to use for future game development.

With something like this you should be able to implement the drawing of different states, and state changes in the callbacks. Either by show/hide divs, or drawing different buffers/graphics to a canvas.

To create states:

```
// initially hide the divs using css or js

state.add("welcome",
    function () {
        document.getElementById("Welcome").style.display = "block";
    },
    function () {
        document.getElementById("Welcome").style.display = "none";
    }
);

state.add("level01",
    function () {
        document.getElementById("Game").style.display = "block";
    },
    function () {
        document.getElementById("Game").style.display = "none";
    }
);

state.add("end",
    function () {
        document.getElementById("GameOver").style.display = "block";
    }
);
```

The second function is optional (actually both are, but such a state would do nothing).

To switch states (assuming we have added 3 states; "welcome", "level01" and "end"):

```
state.enter("welcome");

//... at some point welcome changes state using following:
state.enter("level01");

//... at the end of level1:
state.enter("end");
```

Code:

```
var state = (function () {
    "use strict";
    var currentState = -1,
        stateNames = [],
        stateCallbacks = [];

    return {
        current: function () {
            if (currentState >= 0) {
                return stateNames[currentState];
            }
        },
        add: function (name, onEnter, onExit) {
            var index = stateNames.indexOf(name);
            if (index !== -1) {
                throw "State " + name + " already exist!";
            }
            stateCallbacks.push({
                enterState: onEnter || false,
                exitState: onExit || false
            });
            stateNames.push(name);
        },
        remove: function (name) {
            var index = stateNames.indexOf(name);
            if (index === -1) {
                throw "State " + name + " not found!";
            }
            stateNames.splice(index, 1);
            stateCallbacks.splice(index, 1);
        },
        enter: function (name) {
            var index = stateNames.indexOf(name);
            if (index === -1) {
                throw "State " + name + " not found!";
            }
            if (stateCallbacks[currentState].exitState) {
                stateCallbacks[currentState].exitState();
            }
            currentState = index;
            if (stateCallbacks[index].enterState) {
                stateCallbacks[index].enterState();
            }
        },
        exit: function () {
            if (currentState === -1) {
                throw "Not currently in any state";
            }
            if (stateCallbacks[currentState].exitState) {
                stateCallbacks[currentState].exitState();
            }
            currentState = -1;
        }
    };
}());
```

Additional comments:

The structure with the anonymous function wrapping the code is a module pattern for javascript from http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html. This is similar to a namespace in other languages.

For possibly better performance of lookups (implemented here as Array.indexOf(name)), you might want to add an object with string keys associated with index values, especially for large number of states (ie. a game with 100+ levels, or a different use case where states are switched more intensively). I've not benchmarked this though, so it is highly speculative. In theory an array search is n - 1 times slower than a hashtable lookup (which objects are likely implemented as).

Edit:

1. Fixed bug in code. state.add now checks for existing names.
2. Added disclaimer.
3. Added example of how to show/hide divs from callbacks.
4. Removed disclaimer, replaced code with improved version.